# How to select an employee in SQL, compared to another employee

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new here on the site, I'm learning databases independently, and there's a question I've been trying for a long time, and I decided to ask it here

**The question has such a database:**

- Person (p-id, name, title, hourly-rate, title)
- Topics (t-name, description)
- Workshops (p-id, t-name, hourly-credit)
- Employees (e-id, name, address, mobile)
- EmpTraining (e-id, p-id, t-name)

Persona - The lecturer has a unique ID, name, degree, cost per hour

Topics - the topics in which workshops are delivered. Each topic has a unique name (time management, budget management, etc.) and description.

Workshop - A workshop delivered by a specific lecturer on a specific topic. (Several lecturers can deliver a workshop on the same topic and a lecturer can deliver workshops on different topics) Each workshop is defined as the number of hours that entitle the employee to the training allowance.

Employee - The employee has a unique ID, address and telephone name.

EmpTraining - Each employee is documented in all the workshops he has taken

Example of the database I built, I want to point out that the example here is from a test I failed, the database itself I added is just an example, it does not belong to the exercise itself, but that way it is easier for me to explain, and that way easier to understand.

**https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrDLMHhsquiFQmZT7uS3Z9/0**

**I need to write it in code in SQL, two things:**

1. Return the names of the employees who have undergone at least the same series of workshops as the outstanding employee whose employee number is 100.

*In this question I have to return the names of all the workers, who did all the workshop that a worker with number 100 did*

i try to write, i dont thing that is right, because i am not sure how to select same series of workshops:

```
select name
from Persona as p1, Workshops as w1
where exist {
select *
from Persona as p2, Workshops as w2
where p2.p-id = 100 AND w1.p-is != w2.p-id and w1.t-name = w2.t-name
}
```

2. Return the names of all the employees who have accumulated the number of hours of entitlement to training higher than that of the outstanding employee whose employee number is 100.

*In this question I have to return the names of all the employees, that the number of hours they did for training is greater than the hours that employee number 100 did*

I did not make it 2, was hard to me.

I would be very happy to help, I have been trying to do this for two weeks, thank you very much.

**I want to point out that I do not have the tables with the data, this is a question from a test I had, I do not know how to make tables for it, I need an answer that is similar to the solution, like a pseudo-code**

Comment: I don't mean to be derogatroy, but you need to learn to walk before you can run.  Start by learning the correct syntax for joining tables.  Here's one possible solution to question 1 to help you get started: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrDLMHhsquiFQmZT7uS3Z9/0

Comment: thank you for help, Did you mean to send me your example? I see what I wrote down.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to click save.  I've written it out again, and saved it this time!   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrDLMHhsquiFQmZT7uS3Z9/1

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks a lot for the help, I see you wrote down 2 answers, is that an answer for both sections?

Comment: No, it's two steps to show how I arrived at a solution to question one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your example, I'm expecting by Employees you mean Employees table and by no of hours they did you mean hourly_credit in Workshop table, then below are the queries -

1st Query Can be like -

```
SELECT e.e_id FROM Employees e inner join EmpTraining et on e.e_id = et.e_id where et.t_name in (
    SELECT t_name FROM EmpTraining where e_id = 100 
) 
GROUP BY et.e_id 
having count(DISTINCT et.t_name) >= (SELECT count(DISTINCT t_name) 
FROM EmpTraining where e_id = 100);
```

Here first I'm filtering rows on the basis of workshop name of employee id 100, using below sub query

```
SELECT t_name FROM EmpTraining where e_id = 100
```

Then if we group the result set and then compare distinct count with the distinct count of workshops of employee hundred we can get the employees set we want

Note: Result will contain employee with id - 100 as well to exclude it from the result we can add another condition in where like -

```
AND e.e_id != 100
```

2 nd Query

```
SELECT any_value(e.name) as name 
    FROM Employees e inner join EmpTraining et on e.e_id = et.e_id inner join  Workshops w on et.t_name = w.t_name 
    GROUP BY et.e_id 
    having sum(w.hourly_credit) > (
        SELECT sum(w.hourly_credit) 
        FROM Workshops w inner join EmpTraining etg on etg.t_name = w.t_name 
        where etg.e_id = 100
    );
```

Here I'm grouping rows of EmpTraining on the basis of e_id and comparing sum of hourly_credit with the sum of hourly_credit of employee id 100 EmpTrainings

Comment: @Haham Let me know if it works as you're expecting

Comment: The `Person` table holds the instructors/lecturers, the `Employees` table holds (surprise!) the employees.  The `Workshops` table holds the available training, the `EmpTraining` table holds the workships attended per employee.  This I gathered both from the table naming convention, and the descriptions given in the question, but also by looking at the OP's db-fiddle.

Comment: @AbhaySehgal Thanks a lot for the help, but it does not work for me, I ran the code you wrote, in the SQL database, but in my opinion I should get the name of alice, because she participates in everything that worker number 100 participant

Comment: @MatBailieThanks for the explanation, I misunderstand by checking the example mentioned in the question. Haham, Please check my updated answer, It should work as expected

Comment: I down voted, for the reasons I already gave.  I've removed my down-vote following your edit (though I haven't checked it work, I'll trust the OP).